# Counting permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ satisfying a certain condition

Tags: combinatorics

Help.. I dont understand this problem. Please show me how did you do and why after you answer this.. Thank you!

> The number of permutations of the elements $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is $n!$. How many of these permutations have the property that the sum of every two consecutive elements of the permutation is odd?

Comment: Please provide a descriptive title. Avoid calling out for help. Show your work,  what you have tried, where you're stuck. Also, type the problem in the body of the text: images tend to be lost in servers.

Comment: We want to count the sequences of the shape odd, even, odd, even, and so on or (maybe) even, odd, even, odd, and so on. There some differences of detail between $n$ even and $n$ odd. You might want to look in detail at $n=6$ and $n=7$.  You may prefer to think in terms of men and women.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Start by trying some examples.

- If $n=1$, the only permutation is $1$, which has the desired property.
- If $n=2$, the permutations are $12$ and $21$, both of which have the desired property.
- If $n=3$, the possible permutations are $123,132,213,231,312$, and $321$. Of these only $123$ and $321$ have the desired property, because each of the others has an adjacent pair $13$ or $31$ with even sum.

One more, but let’s think ahead a little this time. We’ve already seen in the case $n=3$ that we can’t have $1$ and $3$ adjacent to each other, because their sum is even. Clearly we also can’t have $2$ and $4$ adjacent to each other. Thus, if we start with $1$, the next element of the permutation must be $2$ or $4$, and it must be followed by $3$. This gives us the permutations $1234$ and $1432$. We could start with $3$ instead, in which case the second element would again have to be $2$ or $4$, and the next would have to be $1$, giving us $3214$ and $3412$. That’s $4$ permutations so far, each starting with one of the odd digits.

We could just as well start with an even digit, but then the next digit would have to be odd, and the third would have to be the other even digit. This gives us another $4$ permutations with the desired property: $2142,2341,4123$, and $4321$. And that’s it: any of the other $12$ permutations will have either two consecutive odd numbers, whose sum is even, or two consecutive even numbers, whose sum is also even.

If $a_n$ is the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with the desired property, we’ve now seen that $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=2$, and $a_4=8$. More important, the discussion in connection with the case $n=4$ brings out the key point: **we want the permutations that alternate odd and even elements**. Try to find a way to count those. You will want to consider two separate cases, one for odd $n$ and one for even $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if the sum of two consecutive numbers is odd then one of the numbers is odd and one is even. We can see that this means the permutation must have alternating odd and even numbers.

If $n$ is odd, we have one more odd number than even number and so we must begin and end in an odd number in this permutation. There are $\frac {(n-1)}{2}$ even numbers and $\frac{(n+1)}{2}$ odd numbers and these can be permuted within their positions. This gives us $\frac{n-1}{2} ! \frac{n+1}{2} !$ permutations if $n$ is odd.

If $n$ is even we can either start with an odd or even number, but then the permutation must alternate parities. again there are $\frac{n}{2}$ even and odd numbers and these can be permuted within their positions. This gives us $2 \frac{n}{2} ! \frac{n}{2} !$ permutations if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

odd sum = odd + even

so the numbers must be intercalated in the form: {even, odd, even, odd, ...} or {odd, even, odd, ...} ... (*)

assume n is even

Then you would have two groups each with n/2 elements, as your problem states this can be permuted with $(\frac{n}{2})! $ ways, since both groups are independent you have $(\frac{n}{2})! \times (\frac{n}{2})! $ since there are two forms (*) you have: 
$$2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)! \times \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)! $$

assume n is odd:

then the numbers of odds numbers is equal the number of even numbers plus 1 proceding the same way as before you will have:
(However if you start with an even number, an odd number won't be next to an even number, since there's one more element) So the only possibility is {odd, even, odd, ...}
$$\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)! \times \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)! $$